# Hydrogen anion system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

For the H- system,how we calculate the energies correct to the first order for the ground state and first excited state. Is it possible for a single proton to hold two electrons and still be stable?

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. Can you explain what you have tried already and perhaps ask a more specific question?

Comment: @DanielSank how to calculate the first order energy correction using perturbation theory for H minus system? what is the unperturbed hamiltonian for that?

Comment: You say "to the first order", but you don't say to the first order in *what*.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible for a single proton to hold two electrons and still be stable?

Yes, such a quantum system really exists: $H^-$ anions occur quite abundantly in alkali metal hydrides like $NaH$, $LiH$ and borohydride complex anions. They are stable but very powerful reducing agents, hence their frequent use in organic synthesis.

Calculation of the bound states of the hydride anion would normally be carried out by finding the eigenstates of the relevant Schrödinger equation. Unfortunately there are no analytical solutions for two electron atoms (see also Helium), although numerically computed solutions can be found.

Empirically photoelectric spectroscopy can be used to determine the energy levels of atoms and simple molecules. But according [to the abstract of this paper](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.38.643), the hydride anion *has only one bound state* (the ground state).

Comment: It is worth noting that computerized minimization of two (or even few) electron systems is "solved". Meaning that the algorithms are known to find the solutions to whatever precision of the the computational horsepower and patience for. Alas they do not yield analytic solutions.

Comment: @dmckee: yes, I've edited that in. It was an oversight: I've used computational quantum chemistry quite a few times. Thank you.

Comment: thank you...could you please help me with this question too http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/211215/nature-of-energy-levels-in-perturbation-theory